# How to create a list if it doesn't exist and add to list if it does

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
mappings = {"some_key": 3}
```

or it could look like this:

```
mappings = {"some_key": [4,5,6]}
```

Say I have a value 100 and a key of "some_key" in this function:

```
def add_to_mappings(key, value):
    if key in mappings:
        mappings[key] = ?
```

and I either want to add to the list if it exists or create one if it does not. At the end, I want my mappings to look like either:

```
   mappings = {"some_key": [3, 100]}
```

or

```
   mappings = {"some_key": [4,5,6,100]}
```

Comment: You could probably use default dict and fill it with a default value of '-1' and call the dictionary with the key and check whether or not the value is '-1'. After that, it should be pretty trivial to get where you want.

Comment: You can check if the value is a list with `isinstance(value, list)`

Comment: Seems a bit silly to not handle the values consistently. If there's only one item why not initialize a list with one element? You may think having a scalar for a single value is better but it really isn't.

Comment: If *all* values in `mappings` are supposed to be lists, this would be an excellent job for a `collections.defaultdict(list)` -- that way you can *always*, unconditionally, use `append()`, as the first time you refer to a key, an empty list will be created for it as a value.

Comment: Why does the question title refer to a list but the question body asks about a dict? I feel like this should be edited as this does not answer the question I had (what the title is)

Answer (score 7):

Without `defaultdict`:

```py
mappings = dict()

def add_to_mappings(key, value):
  try:
    mappings[key].append(100)
  except KeyError:
    mappings[key] = [100]
```

With `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

mappings = defaultdict(list)

def add_to_mappings(key, value):
  mappings[key].append(value)
```

**Edit:** I misunderstood the original requirements, to take an item if it already existed and create a list out of it and the new item, then the first example could be changed to this:

```py
mappings = dict(foo=3)

def add_to_mappings(key, value):
  try:
    mappings[key].append(100)
  except KeyError:
    mappings[key] = [100]
  except AttributeError:
    mappings[key] = [mappings[key], value]

add_to_mappings("foo", 5)
# mappings ==> { "foo": [3, 5] }
```

Comment: how do I convert defaultdict to dict again?

Comment: @Jwan622 Same as you convert anything x = to dict: `dict(mappings)`. Works the other way too: `defaultdict(x, list)`.

Comment: Try-catch method is neat!

Answer (score 3):

You check if something is a list with `isinstance(x, list)`. You can extract existing values from a dictionary and replace the value with simple assignment. So:

```
def add_to_mappings(d, key, value): # Remember to pass in the dict too!
    if key in d:
        # The value is present
        v = d[k]
        if isinstance(v, list):
            # Already a list: just append to it
            v.append(value)
        else:
            # Not a list: make a new list
            d[k] = [v, value]
    else:
        # Not present at all: make a new list
        d[key] = [value]
```